# Add input with jquery mask

Tags: jquery, mask

Hello guys I have this script below that is adding input, but I'm not able to insert the masks.
The plugin I'm using
https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

In the first field the mask is running, when adding it is not adding the mask.

Could help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
            $(wrapper).append("<div><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext[]\" id=\"date\"/><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div>");
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
});    
</script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="date"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#date').mask('00/00/0000');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change id selector `#date`  class `.date` because you can't have more than one element with the same id.

Second thing you need to move the  `$('.date').mask('00/00/0000');` inside the `$(document).ready(function() {})` method.

Third thing, you have to  bind mask to the newly created an input element.
Below is the copy of your working code after the amending the above suggested changes.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            $(wrapper).append("<div><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext[]\" class=\"date\"/><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div>");
            $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        })
        $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
    });
</script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="date"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#date').mask('00/00/0000');
</script>
```

Comment: Anytime @Conseld

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('#date').mask('00/00/0000');` inside `$(document).ready(function() {})`
As it is not guaranteed document has finished loading when you run it in a script block like this.
Doco: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cleaned up.

```
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
var button = $(".add_field_button");
var input = $("#date");

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    wrapper.append("<div><input type=\"text\" name=\"mytext[]\" id=\"date\"/><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div>");
});

wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
})

input.mask('00/00/0000');
```